# I have two divs with the same class and ID.how do I use within, so that I can simulate clicks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I work on a Rails project that uses Capybara for front end testing. I ended up in a situation where I have duplicate div tags with the same ID. How can I use capybara scoping so that I select only one of them and perform my tests within that div?

Comment: Can you fix the HTML to be valid instead? `id` attributes are supposed to be unique.

Comment: fixing the HTML breaks JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the html

```
<div id="wrapper1">
  <div id="conflict">...</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2">
  <div id="conflict">...</div>
</div>
```

then you should be able to do

```
within("#wrapper1") do
  find("#conflict") # will find the matching element inside the wrapper1 div
end
```

However you really should just fix the HTML and any JS that uses those divs, since it is technically illegal HTML which can cause any number of unpredictable behaviors

Comment: I know, but I need the tests first.